# Error 6 - Overflow on one computer but not on another

Tags: vba, excel

I've created an Excel VBA macro to import large numbers of .txt files from a folder into a single spreadsheet. I finally got it working on my computer and successfully tested it on two others, then sent it over to a coworker, who started running it but ran into an Overflow error around here in the code:

```
currentfilename = filename & "light.txt"
j = 1
Open currentfilename For Input As #1
Do Until EOF(1)
    Line Input #1, textline
    Cells(j + 1, 3) = Val(Right(textline, Len(textline) - InStr(textline, vbTab)))
    j = j + 1
Loop
Close #1
```

I had her email me the contents of the folder she's selecting with the macro and when I ran it, it ran just fine. Is there any reason that one computer might encounter an overflow error with this code, but another one would not? We're both using Excel 2016 on the latest OSX.

Comment: What processors / flavor of OSX are the different computers using? That is, 32-bit vs 64-bit?

Comment: Are the locales different?  `Val` isn't locale aware in regard to decimal separators. Note that you should also use [`FreeFile`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg264526.aspx) instead of hard coded file handles and add error handling to ensure open handles get closed.

Comment: Can you reproduce the issue with that snippet? If so, what's the value of `j` when the overflow occurs? And what's the type of `j`? If it's `Integer`, make that `Long`. If it's undeclared, *declare it*. If you can't reproduce the issue with that snippet, please see [mcve].